# Rails ajax call 404 not found routing error

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I was playing around with ruby on rails and tried making ajax call but kept seeing an error.
So in my index.html.erb, I have a button with id test. And in the same index file, I have

```
("#test").click(function(){
    $.ajax({ 
      type: 'POST', 
      url: '/test', 
      data: {key: 'value'}, 
      dataType: 'script',
    });
});
```

So, when I click on the button with id test, I keep seeing

```
POST http://localhost:3000/test 404 (Not Found)
```

I cannot seem to figure out why because in my config/routes.rb, I have get '/test', to: 'prompts#test' and in my promptsController, I have

```
def test
  puts "enters here"
end
```

Comment: add output of `rake routes` in question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your routes you say you have

```
get '/test', to: 'prompts#test'
```

But notice that in your call to `$.ajax()` you're using **POST**.

Instead you need a route for

```
post '/test', to: 'prompts#test'
```